# NG-IDLE Version 13.0.0 onwards is triggering on time out event, even if user is active

Tags: ng-idle

On Time out event triggering even user is active

I have my current angular application is upgraded to angular 17 from version 14 and i upgrade the ng-idle version to 14.0.0 from version 11.1.0.
After the upgrade my existing ng-idle implementation is not working.
When the user is active i still get the OnTimeout event triggered and log out user from the app.

Further debugging the issue I tried to downgrading only the ng-idle version to 12.0.4 it started working with angular 17.

As per the security requirement my application needs to be on the latest version of all third party library i am using.

Can anyone help me to understand what could be the potential issue here why the on time out event is triggering even user is active.

I really appreciate in advance any help on this.